# Oracle Select Query : Where col_name = N'text' What does the N stands for?

Tags: performance, oracle

I sometimes see in a select query a where-clause like this :
where col_name = N'text'

What does this N mean?

I know that in T-SQL, it is a Unicode parsing character, but what does it mean for Oracle?
Is it the same?

How does it affect the performance of a query?
Like, if I use it on a CHAR-column, what's the loss or profit (I doubt it) of the N-character?

I've searched a lot on google, but only found it for T-SQL, not for oracle.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I believe its for National characterset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Unicode literal. [See the documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm#i1006315).

I suppose one could write a test script to see how this function affects a query in their own environment.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. Couldn't find it. I will write a short function to test the behaviour of it.